# How to print two different dictionaries on the same line using Python?

Tags: python

i have a problem i don't know how to print two dictionary on the same line.

I have:

```
Fantasy = {"Gotham":[city, 2000], "Smallville":[town, 40], "Nuketown":[town,60]}
Real = {"London":[city, 1500], "Whitby":[town, 40], "Liverpool":[city, 1000]}
```

i've tried this (pass):

```
listFantasy = dictList(Fantasy)
listReal = dictList(Real)    
def dictList (dict):
       list = []
         for key, value in dict_.iteritems(): # Create list form dict
            temp = [key,value]
            lista_finale.append(temp)
       return list

for list1, list2 in zip(listFantasy, listReal):
        print list1[0]
        for listValue1, listValue2 in zip(list1[1:],list2[1:]):
            listValue1.sort(key = lambda x: x[1], reverse = True)
            listValue2.sort(key = lambda x: x[1], reverse = True)
            for value1, value2 in zip(listValue1, listValue2):
                print " \n %-10s \t %-10s" % (valore1[0], valore1[1]),"\t\t\t\t %-10s \t %-10s" % (valore2[0], valore2[1])
```

OUTPUT:

```
Gotham           London 
   city 2000        city 1500        
NukeTow        Liverpool
   town 60          city 1000
Smallville     Whitby
   town 40          town 40
```

But this solution is very slow, it takes me about 30 seconds, I need to know how to directly print the two dictionaries online in the same way, without serious waste of time on the code execution.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried so far.

Comment: Your declaration is bloken, since you will have `NameError` while running it.

Comment: Also note that the order cannot be guaranteed (you could have `Gotham` and `Whitby` in the same line). And *quote your strings...*

Comment: thankyou for updating the question. The trouble now is that your code doesn't run: First line has `NameError: name 'Gotham' is not defined`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May be like this?

```
>>> Fantasy = {'Gotham':['city', 2000], 'Smallville':['town', 30]}
>>> Real = {'London':['city', 1000], 'Whitby':['town', 40]}
>>> print '{:15}\t\t{:15}'.format('Fantasy','Real')    
>>> for c1,c2 in zip(sorted(Fantasy),sorted(Real)):
        print '{:10}{:5}\t\t{:10}{:5}'.format(c1, Fantasy[c1][1], c2,Real[c2][1])

Fantasy             Real    
Gotham     2000     London     1000
Smallville   30     Whitby       40
```

Comment: why is Smallville, London on the same line  when op also asked for Gotham and London to be on same line

Comment: In python `dict`s don't have an order of their keys.

Comment: @AlbinPaul Sorting added.

Answer (score 2):

**Try this:-**

```
Fantasy = {"Gotham":["city", 2000], "Smallville":["town", 30]}
Real = {"London":["city", 1000], "Whitby":["town", 40]}

for i,j in zip(Fantasy,Real):
    print (i,end='')
    print (" ",Fantasy[i][-1],end = '')
    print (" ",j,end='')
    print (" ",Real[j][-1])
```

Comment: i hope this will help you

Answer (score 2):

If you want to join and align an arbitrary number of dictionaries (maybe, not only Fantasy and Real), with multiple object types (maybe, not only city and town), you may find `pandas` useful:

```
Fantasy = {'Gotham':['city', 2000], 'Smallville':['town', 30]}
Real = {'London':['city', 1000], 'Whitby':['town', 40]}
# You have to code 'Fantasy' and 'Real' as strings, for Python to interpret and print them
dicts = {'Fantasy': Fantasy, 'Real': Real}

import pandas as pd
frames = []
for key, value in dicts.items():
    # Create a small table from each dict
    frame = pd.DataFrame(value, index=['type', 'size']).T.reset_index().set_index('type')
    # Add an extra column name (e.g. 'Fantasy')
    frame.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([[key]*2, frame.columns])
    frames.append(frame)
print(pd.concat(frames, axis=1))
```

This code prints a little bit more than you wanted, but I think this extra info is useful, and must be shown explicitly:

```
         Fantasy          Real      
           index  size   index  size
type                                
city      Gotham  2000  London  1000
town  Smallville    30  Whitby    40
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
print(Fantasy, Real)
```

If you want a custom format, then looping over the two is the only option. Consult [`IO Formatting`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) documentation.